# Tensor multiplication with numpy tensordot

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a tensor U composed of n matrices of dimension (d,k) and a matrix V of dimension (k,n).

I would like to multiply them so that the result returns a matrix of dimension (d,n) in which column j is the result of the matrix multiplication between the matrix j of U and the column j of V.

[image]

One possible way to obtain this is:

```
for j in range(n):
    res[:,j] = U[:,:,j] * V[:,j]
```

I am wondering if there is a faster approach using `numpy` library. In particular I'm thinking of the [`np.tensordot()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) function.

This small snippet allows me to multiply a single matrix by a scalar, but the obvious generalization to a vector is not returning what I was hoping for.

```
a = np.array(range(1, 17))
a.shape = (4,4)
b = np.array((1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
r1 = np.tensordot(b,a, axes=0)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What software are you using to draw your images?

Comment: @hlin117 - I used keynote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. The first thing that comes to mind is [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
# some fake data
gen = np.random.RandomState(0)
ni, nj, nk = 10, 20, 100
U = gen.randn(ni, nj, nk)
V = gen.randn(nj, nk)

res1 = np.zeros((ni, nk))
for k in range(nk):
    res1[:,k] = U[:,:,k].dot(V[:,k])

res2 = np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik', U, V)

print(np.allclose(res1, res2))
# True
```

`np.einsum` uses [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) to express tensor contractions. In the expression `'ijk,jk->ik'` above, `i`,`j` and `k` are subscripts that correspond to the different dimensions of `U` and `V`. Each comma-separated grouping corresponds to one of the operands passed to `np.einsum`  (in this case `U` has dimensions `ijk` and `V` has dimensions `jk`). The `'->ik'` part specifies the dimensions of the output array. Any dimensions with subscripts that aren't present in the output string are summed over.

`np.einsum` is incredibly useful for performing complex tensor contractions, but it can take a while to fully wrap your head around how it works. You should take a look at the examples in the documentation (linked above).

---

Some other options:

1. Element-wise multiplication with [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), followed by summation:

   ```
   res3 = (U * V[None, ...]).sum(1)
   ```
2. `inner1d` with a load of transposing:

   ```
   from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

   res4 = inner1d(U.transpose(0, 2, 1), V.T)
   ```

Some benchmarks:

```
In [1]: ni, nj, nk = 100, 200, 1000

In [2]: %%timeit U = gen.randn(ni, nj, nk); V = gen.randn(nj, nk)
   ....: np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik', U, V)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop

In [3]: %%timeit U = gen.randn(ni, nj, nk); V = gen.randn(nj, nk)
(U * V[None, ...]).sum(1)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 59.7 ms per loop

In [4]: %%timeit U = gen.randn(ni, nj, nk); V = gen.randn(nj, nk)
inner1d(U.transpose(0, 2, 1), V.T)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 45.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please add the explanation on how the function is working? For instance, how would the function call change if U instead of being `(ni,nj,nk)` was `(nk,ni,nj)`?

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looking at the op's question i notice that he wants to multiply (i,j,k) with (k,i), in the accepted answer it is ijk, jk -> ik, but it should be ijk, ik -> ij.

Comment: @wedran OP wants a reduction over the second axis of `U` and the first axis of `V`, which in my example is subscript `j`. With his original notation it would be `dkn,kn->dn` (which is equivalent to `ijk,jk->ik`).

Comment: Current link for einsum: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html