# How to do a tensor multiplication of two matrices A(m,n) and B (n,k) so that i get C(m,n,k) .. Is it possible to do it using dataframes

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, multiplication

How to do a tensor multiplication of two matrices A(m,n) and B (n,k) so that i get C(m,n,k) using python.. Is it possible to do it using dataframes or numpy ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensor multiplication with numpy tensordot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786249/tensor-multiplication-with-numpy-tensordot)

Comment: The `einsum` expression for that link is `'ijk,jk->ik'`, which doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple broadcasted outer product in `numpy`:

```
In [560]: m,n,k=2,3,4
In [561]: A=np.ones((m,n))
In [562]: B=np.ones((n,k))
In [563]: C=A[:,:,None]*B[None,:,:]
In [564]: C.shape
Out[564]: (2, 3, 4)
```

The process is also easily done with `np.einsum`, though it is a bit of overkill for that, since you aren't summing over any dimension (as with a `np.dot` product):

```
In [565]: np.einsum('mn,nk->mnk',A,B).shape
Out[565]: (2, 3, 4)
```

Similar question from 2 days ago

[numpy: broadcast multiplication over one common axis of two 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644851/numpy-broadcast-multiplication-over-one-common-axis-of-two-2d-arrays)

Given the broad nature of your question there probably is a lot about my answer that you don't understand.  But you need to read some of the docs first.